# What do you call a UX component that opens a box with a chat or virtual assistant?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, widget

I mean that bar that appears at the bottom of some sites, saying something like "Chat with customer support". When you click on it, it slides up to become a chat box.

Comment: Ex.: liveperson.com, zopim.com

Comment: I guess "Live Support" or "Chat" with an icon relating to it.

Comment: But that isn't really limited to chat or support, I'm looking if there's a name for the component that has a button that's always inside the view, that when clicked opens a dialog or some other box that allows for user interaction.

Comment: A nuisance, personally.

Answer (score 2):

The only name I could find is **bottom flyout**, although this term appears to be specific to a WordPress plugin.

I'd personally refer to it as a **bottom** or **footer floating tab**.

[image: Flyout]

Answer (score -2):

A component which expands on click is called Accordion or Expandable in web development world.

Comment: But that's when you have several tabs/topics and you open one of them. I'm asking about a floating button that expands to a dialog or other component that allows user interaction.

Comment: Tadda simple, floating Accordion, or chat bubble

Comment: I would suggest you expand on this answer by providing relevant citations and support for your answer.